# compare pd.series with difference length and show only difference values

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pd.series: `one=pd.Series([536,1226,2370,2996,10256,10592])` and
`two=pd.Series([812,1172,2639,3157])`. So I want compare them row by row with some condition:        first if `one-two>=0` -> if true "we good", else print values where difference >0, but if `len` of them different as in example, show also "extra" values(two last values in `one` pd.series).
Expected output:
one(1226) and two(1172) and one(10256,10592).
I trying `pd.compare` and `pd.isna` in for..else statement but not really successfully.

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: can you explain what do you want to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative:

```
>>> pd.concat([one, two], axis=1).loc[~one.sub(two).lt(0)]

       0       1
1   1226  1172.0
4  10256     NaN
5  10592     NaN
```

Comment: Thk, how convert output to list? I want to append output to my "log" list

Comment: `list(zip(out[0], out[1]))`?

Comment: or `list(zip(out.dropna()[0], out.dropna()[1])) + out.loc[out.isna().any(axis=1), 0].tolist()`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `concat` and `loc`:

```
>>> df = pd.concat([one, two], axis=1)
>>> df.loc[df[0].ge(df[1]) | df[1].isna()]
       0       1
1   1226  1172.0
4  10256     NaN
5  10592     NaN
>>>
```